# Angularjs with Internet Explorer 11, security issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using Angularjs for some months and it works like a charms in Chrome/Firefox/Safari but face some problems with IE11 and Edge.

It seems my problem come from ng-src since images are not displayed and src attribute is never set.

Here is the code:

```
 <div class="cell col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="obj in DATA.objects | orderBy:objectsOrder track by $index ">
    <div ng-click="setCurrent($event, obj, '{{'obj_nav_' + $index}}')">
        <img ng-src="{{formatURL(obj.Id, obj.img.fileName)}}"></img>
        <div>
            <p ng-bind="obj.name"/>
            <p ng-bind="obj.address"/>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

formatURL is a scope function that format the URL to get images, for instance the formatted url will be "https://user1:mdp@mydomain.com/objId/imageName".

Here is the error:

Error: A security issue has occurred.

at Aa (http://192.168.9.97/web/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:147:46)
   at Anonymous function (http://192.168.9.97/web/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:137:142)
   at Z.prototype.$set (http://192.168.9.97/web/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:76:149)
   at Anonymous function (http://192.168.9.97/web/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:242:344)
   at Anonymous function (http://192.168.9.97/web/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:77:72)
   at m (http://192.168.9.97/web/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:7:320)
   at Z.prototype.$set (http://192.168.9.97/web/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:77:49)
   at Anonymous function (http://192.168.9.97/web/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:71:500)
   at Anonymous function (http://192.168.9.97/web/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:95:444)
   at Anonymous function (http://192.168.9.97/web/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:128:156)

This error message was thrown using Angularjs 1.4.7. Note that I was using 1.3.0-rc5 when I first faced the problem then I update Angular but still got the same problem. I got exactly the same error in Edge.

Comment: what if create a `formatURL` filter replacing the scope function?

Comment: I guess you're testing it in a local server. Does it happen when not in local?

Comment: Got the same error when served fron remote server

Comment: @Max, I'm french so I understand the french part but I think you should translate it : Error: Un problème de sécurité s'est produit. > A security issue has occurred.

Comment: @StrandedKid good idea

Comment: Anyway, I dug a bit where this error could come from and did not find too much, but you should look at these points maybe : page is loading through http but images through https (should'nt be a problem but with IE you never know), you pass a password in the url and maybe IE does not like it because it has some browser conf that blocks it.

Comment: Http/https were not the problem but login and password in url were. Still can figure out why Angularjs return such a complex error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer here [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/834489).
Microsoft doesn't allow user to use http://login:password@url format to prevent hidden url.