# AngularJs: Error: A security problem occurred in IE11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

We have developed a site using AngularJS 1.2.x version. The data to be displayed is got as a JSON and we have used angular expresions to populate these.

In the JSON response we have a URL in this format http://username@site.com. This is getting rendered properly in Chrome, FF. But in IE11 we are getting the following exception

**Error: A security problem occurred.**

```
at xa (site/angularjs.d7ecc107a031818a8e5269a12c25ec8e.js:124:230)
at Anonymous function (site/angularjs.d7ecc107a031818a8e5269a12c25ec8e.js:116:319)
at Anonymous function (site/angularjs.d7ecc107a031818a8e5269a12c25ec8e.js:116:319)
at Anonymous function (site/angularjs.d7ecc107a031818a8e5269a12c25ec8e.js:116:319)
at r (site/angularjs.d7ecc107a031818a8e5269a12c25ec8e.js:7:390)
at start (site/angularjs.d7ecc107a031818a8e5269a12c25ec8e.js:285:470)
at c (site/angularjs.d7ecc107a031818a8e5269a12c25ec8e.js:282:408)
at G (site/angularjs.d7ecc107a031818a8e5269a12c25ec8e.js:284:243)
at Anonymous
```

We found a similar question in([Angularjs with Internet Explorer 11, security issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411507/angularjs-with-internet-explorer-11-security-issue)) but the link provided in the accepted answer is no longer valid.

Is there any workaround to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not possible, it's a security matter of IE and there's no workaround for that other than changing the url format to something IE accepts.

About the broken link, for some reason the english version of that article is not available anymore, but I've switched the locales in the url and managed to find other languages including `pt-BR`, `pt-PT`, `es-ES` and based on your profile `hi-IN`, if that doesn't work for you, you can try to Google Translate one of them to english or even try different lacale in the article url.

Those are the ones I tried and they're not broken:

- Portuguese (Portugal) : `pt-PT` - https://support.microsoft.com/pt-pt/help/834489
- Chinese (China) : `zh-cn` - https://support.microsoft.com/zh-cn/help/834489
- Portuguese (Brazil): `pt-BR` - https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/834489
- Spanish (Spain): `es-ES` - https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/834489
- Hindi (India): `hi-IN` - https://support.microsoft.com/hi-in/help/834489
- Japanese (Japan): `ja-jp` - https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/834489

There ought to have [more locales](https://forums.asp.net/post/2310972.aspx) available but I'm not wiling to test all of them.